# Extracting data from JSON file into Javascript for use as autocomplete in a web form input

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, forms, autocomplete

I don't work with Javascript often and therefore my knowledge is very very very limited.

I have a JSON file (airports.json) that lists the airports iata code, name, city and country:

```
[
{
    "iata": "CPT",
    "name": "Cape Town International Airport",
    "city": "Cape Town",
    "country": "South Africa"
},

{
    "iata": "JNB",
    "name": "OR Tambo International Airport",
    "city": "Johannesburg",
    "country": "South Africa"
},

{
    "iata": "DUR",
    "name": "King Shaka International Airport",
    "city": "Durban",
    "country": "South Africa"
},
]
```

I want to use this information to extract it in a Javascript file (method.js) that takes the information and parse it to return to the user. When the user starts typing in either the IATA code, city or country the script file must search through the different variables ("iata", "name", "city", "country") and compile the results in the autocomplete dropdown box like this:

> Cape Town, Cape Town International (CPT), South Africa

or in coding terms (something like this):

```
city + ', ' + name + '(' + iata + '), ' + country,
```

but when the user clicks on the the result [onSelect], the input field must only have the following:

> Cape Town (CPT)

or, again in coding terms (something like this):

```
city + '(' + iata + ')'
```

How do I get the information from the .json file into the .js file and use it to custom build my own results?

Comment: Use JSON.parse for parsing json data into js object

Answer (score 0):

First part would be to use ajax to get the data. Since it is a static data file load it once then in the ajax callback initialize the `autocomplete` and pass the data array to the plugin.

```
$.getJSON('yourdata.json', function(response){
    var mappedData = $.map(response , function(){ /* up to you to map it*/ })
    $('.airportFrom input').autocomplete({
        lookup: mappedData ,
        .......
    });

    // other autocomplete
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using JQuery, you can use the $.getJSON method to retrieve the json data from the airports.json file.

[$.getJson():  see how it works here](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/)

Remember to put your autocomplete code inside the success function so the code will be run only after the ajax call finish. Something like:

```
$.getJSON("/airports.json")
.success(function( data ) {
    var airportArray = data; // here you get your airport.json data and assing it to your array variable. The data will already be in json format
    // HERE YOU PUT YOUR AUTOCOMPLETE CODE SO YOU CAN USE THE DATA RETRIVIED
})
.error(function(){
    // here you handle the error with the ajax call (doc does not exist, the server does not respond...
});
```